# Unknown module in OllyDbg 2.01 "Assemble" command

Tags: assembly, disassembly, ollydbg

I'm disassembly a crack-me and I want to replace an empty space with the WINAPI SetDlgItemText() which takes three parameters.
I successfully added the three "push" instruction but when I try to assemble `call <JMP.&USER32.SetDlgItemTextA>` OllyDbg says me in red `Unknown module`
 
The same instruction is used a few lines above (by the software, nothing assembled by myself).
**How can I solve this error and call SetDlgItemText?** Binary copy - binary paste doesn't solve the problem (jump in a different section of code, probably because I made a little mess with opcodes)

Here's a screenshot ([full size](http://s17.postimg.org/4z960r73j/Untitled.png)):
[image]

EDIT1: I found the function JMP at address 0x00401460. So I replaced it with that and immediatly ollydbg substituted it with the `call <JMP.&USER32.SetDlgItemTextA>` string. Why can't it do the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [PE File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) a Call to Imported Functions normally are made using the *Import Address Table* (IAT). This structure contain a continuous list of address pointers that would be initialized by the Windows Loader when loading the binary and resolve the imports.

In the Import Directory they're info about the modules imported, for every module, the functions names and functions ordinal imported. In the loading process this info is used to locate the modules and functions to import and the IAT is initialized with the address in memory of the functions imported, that would be already load into memory (in the common import procedure).

What you need to do is search in the binary when there is another call to `SetDlgItemTextA`, according to your question you already have this. The instruction should be some like `CALL [address]` (ex: `CALL [0x401634]`) or `JMP [address]` (ex: `JMP [0x401434]`), note that is call to the address located in that address, not call to that address, is a doble indirection (most probably OllyDB resolve the name of the function and replace this address with the name), in this case you could read the address of the binary representation of the instruction. Your call would be the same, must probably the opcode of the instruction would be `0xFF (Indirect CALL or JMP)`.

The address in the `CALL or JMP` is the address of the pointer to the imported function that the Loader would set with the actual memory address of the imported function.